# Laravel 7 - query with conditions on pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, php-carbon

I'm working on an AirBnb replica and i'm trying to create an api that returns only the sponsored houses.

[DB tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTt3g.png)

The query I wrote can't find any house, can you help me find the error? Thank you!

```
$houses = House::with(['position', 'user', 'messages', 'services', 'visualizations', 'sponsorships'])
         ->whereHas('sponsorships', function($query) {
            $query->whereTime('sponsor_start', '<=', Carbon::now())
                  ->whereTime('sponsor_end', '>', Carbon::now());
         })
         ->where('is_visible','=', 1)
         ->paginate(12);;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sponsor_start` and `sponsor_end` are columns on pivot table

Assuming your relationship definitions are as:

```php
//Sponsorship model
public function houses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(House::class)
        ->withPivot('sponsorship_start', 'sponsorship_end')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

```php
//House model
public function sponsorships()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Sponsorship::class)
        ->withPivot('sponsorship_start', 'sponsorship_end')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

You can try the below - qualifying the columns of pivot table by pivot table name

```php
$houses = House::with(['position', 'user', 'messages', 'services', 'visualizations', 'sponsorships'])
         ->whereHas('sponsorships', function($query) {
            $query->whereTime('house_sponsorship.sponsor_start', '<=', Carbon::now())
                  ->whereTime('house_sponsorship.sponsor_end', '>', Carbon::now());
         })
         ->where('is_visible','=', 1)
         ->paginate(12);;
```

Comment: It gives me: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Glabdugrib Have updated answer to include relationship definition where `withPivot` is used to specify the columns on intermediate table which should be included in relationship query. This should work.